# Can a Dremel Circle Cutter be used on 20mm thick wood?

Tags: powertools

Will the Dremel Circle Cutter cut through 20mm wood? Its just regular wood am using.

[image]

The [product details page](http://www.dremel.com/en-us/Attachments/Pages/ProductDetail.aspx?pid=678-01) on the Dremel site just states:

> Depth adjustment allows easy setting of the correct cutting depth

without indicating what the maximum depth is.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As others have said, this will work, IF you have a sufficiently long bit, that will extend at last 2cm below the base of the jig. The problem is, most such bits for a Dremel tool are not that long. You may be able to use a Rotozip bit, which are longer than the standard Dremel bits.

Next problem is, even if you do find a sufficiently long bit, you need to deal with flexing of the bit, or breakage. These bits are relatively thin, so they can break off. Therefore, you will need to go slowly. Don't push it faster than it wants to cut. If you feel too much resistance, don't push as hard.

Answer (score 2):

You'll have to check the documentation for the specific Dremel tool, and bit you are using.  The circle jig doesn't have much to do with the thickness of material that can be cut, that will be dependent on the tool attached to the jig and the bit being used in the tool.

Answer (score 2):

The circle cutter is simply a jig used to hold the bit in the correct position to ensure a perfect circle cut.

The depth available will depend upon the length of the Dremel bit you use with the circle cutter.

As long as you use a bit that extends 2cm beyond the base of the jig, you'll be fine.